# Как добавить функционал в существующую библиотеку Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, library, github-pages

во время работы столкнулся с необходимостью расширить функционал существующей [библиотеки](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firechat/tree/master). До этого опыта работы с библиотеками у меня не было. Проблема заключается в том каким образом это возможно реализовать?Библиотека представляет собой компонент чата для интеграции с Firebase. Мне необходимо внести изменения в логику и UI компонент библиотеки. В структуре библиотеки присутствует grunt, bower и jekyll который наотрез отказывается запускать имеющийся экземпляр сайта локально. Я слышал про возможность форкнутую библиотеку загрузить в свой Github чтоб использовать в проэкте, но попытки не увенчались успехом. Какие есть пути решения данной проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

Недавно тоже задался подобным вопросом с npm пакетами. Пообсуждали с командой и самым оптимальным решением стало банальное скачивание либы и ручное внедрение в проект в качестве компонента.

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать как вам удалось это сделать? Ибо в этом библиотеке такая странная структура, что непонятен алгоритм реализации внедрения.

Comment: @IvanAfanasiev вроде понятно объяснил. У вас по ссылке на библиотеку есть репозиторий, в котором лежат исходники либы. Вы просто перетягиваете эти исходники в свой проект и редактируете как хотите.